# Ionic Installation Cordova through npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I tried to install `ionic` by using the following code

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

I have set the `http-proxy`, `https-proxy` and `registry` also. I'm working behind the a corporate firewall. Still I can not able to complete the install. TIA

Adding Log:

```
  0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'ionic',
1 verbose cli   'cordova' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.5
3 info using node@v7.4.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData ionic
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData cordova
9 silly fetchNamedPackageData ionic
10 silly mapToRegistry name ionic
11 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
12 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
13 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
13 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'ionic',
13 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
13 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'ionic',
13 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'ionic',
13 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
13 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
13 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
14 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
15 silly fetchNamedPackageData cordova
16 silly mapToRegistry name cordova
17 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
18 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
19 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
19 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'cordova',
19 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
19 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'cordova',
19 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'cordova',
19 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
19 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
19 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
20 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
21 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
22 verbose request no auth needed
23 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:02:56 AM
24 verbose request id 9e32300b5a31ffd6
25 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
26 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
27 verbose request no auth needed
28 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:02:56 AM
29 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
30 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
31 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
32 info attempt registry request try #2 at 9:03:06 AM
33 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
34 info attempt registry request try #2 at 9:03:06 AM
35 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
36 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
37 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
38 info attempt registry request try #3 at 9:04:06 AM
39 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
40 info attempt registry request try #3 at 9:04:06 AM
41 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:165:19)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for ionic { Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:165:19)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:165:19)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for cordova { Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:165:19)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
44 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
45 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of null
45 verbose stack     at Installer.rollbackFailedOptional (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:505:29)
45 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
45 verbose stack     at LOOP (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
45 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:18:7
45 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:331:5
45 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
45 verbose stack     at LOOP (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
45 verbose stack     at chain (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:20:5)
45 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:288:5
45 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:16:22
46 verbose cwd D:\Projs\sftwr
47 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
48 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
49 error node v7.4.0
50 error npm  v4.0.5
51 error Cannot read property 'path' of null
52 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
52 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
53 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Go through this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/)

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @Sivakumar Error trace please...

Comment: 1. ERR! registry error parsing json, 2. ERR! registry error parsing json . Thanks for your time Gandhi, @Aman

Comment: Hi @SivakumarPurushothaman, could you please update your question with the error trace?

Comment: @Tolen added trace..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like npm has a proxy problem. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2472) issue on their GitHub

Answer (score 0):

The problem i faced is i set up the proxy with - (hypen) not with under score(_). So i got the solution just by setting the proxy with _ like `https_proxy`.